# Why does this code output zero and not the biggest difference (which is 7 since it is the biggest difference between subsequent values, not all them)?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;

public class LabProgram {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

      int counter = scnr.nextInt();
      int maxDiff = 0;
      int next = 0;
  
      for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
          int last = scnr.nextInt();
     
         if (i == 0) {
            continue;
         }
     
         int difference = Math.abs(last - next);
     
         if (maxDiff > difference) {
            maxDiff = difference;
         }
     
         last = next;
      }
  
      System.out.println(maxDiff);
  
   }
}
```

This is my code, and it ouputs 0 when it should be outputting 7. Any help here would be much appreciated (I have to use a continue  and a for statement, and I am not allowed to use any while statements as necessities).

Comment: `if (maxDiff > difference)` is the wrong way around: you only remember the new difference if it's *smaller* than the current one.

Comment: Alright, that fixed the 0 issue, but now it's outputting 68. Lol. I think this is a step in the right direction, though, so thank you!

Comment: There's no input data to understand what's going on.  That said, I believe this to be a bug too:
if (maxDiff > difference) { maxDiff = difference; }
should be:
if (difference > maxDiff ) < { maxDiff = difference; }

Let me know

Comment: I actually got it all figured it out. Thank you all for helping me with this!

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign next = last.
Because the value of next(0) is always getting assigned to last so only you are getting zero always

Comment: Alright, this got me closer. Now I just need to figure out why it's outputting 63. Do you have any clue? I do appreciate this. I am starting to understand how this works a bit better.